# pytsk3 - how to get the block size of a file system

Tags: python, computer-forensics

Upon examining the TSK API, I've found a function that [returns the size per block/sector of a file system](http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/docs/api-docs/4.2/structTSK__FS__INFO.html#a07e3175162a0f02e2aadc9b947673d96). I try it out in Python using pytsk3.

```
import pytsk3

#defining the path of the disk image
url="10-ntfs-disk.dd"

#getting an Img_Info object
img=pytsk3.Img_Info(url)

#opening the file system, 32256 is the offset of the file system in bytes
fs=pytsk3.TSK_FS_INFO(img, 32256, pytsk3.TSK_FS_TYPE_NTFS)
print fs.block_size
```

However, the output is "Segmentation fault". I'm not sure what I should do next. On pytsk3's [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/py4n6/pytsk/wiki), the example uses `pytsk3.FS_Info()` to open the file system, though the class doesn't seem to have a function that returns the block size.

Comment: Sample image from http://dftt.sourceforge.net/test10/ .Not able to post more than two links.

Comment: Do you able to install pytsk3 successfully

Answer (score 1):

There is a POSIX system call "[stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)" That retruns you some file system information, you want the content of the variable *st_blksize*. This is available for all POSIX compliant systems which are Linux, Android, Mac but NOT Windows. Note that you can have multiple filesystem mounted therefore stat needs a path or file as parameter which points to any loaction in the file system you want.